# Como puedo imprimir automáticamente con NODE.JS después de un evento

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nodejs, mongodb

Me pueden orientar sobre como o con que librería puedo hacer que desde cualquier computador, ingrese un dato o pinche un botón y al momento de hacer esa acción se genere un evento en otro computador que esta conectado a internet y me imprima un ticket en la impresora USB de dicho computador?.

Un esquema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3):

Puedes hacerlo mediante el patrón [Observer](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_(patr%C3%B3n_de_dise%C3%B1o)) y te puedes apoyar de la librería [RemoteEvents](https://www.npmjs.com/package/remote-events).

Con esta librería es muy sencillo crear un stream end to end para comunicación remota. Te pongo un ejemplo:

```
import net from 'net';

const STREAM_PORT = 7896; // <- importante
const server = net.createServer(con => {
  let remote = new RemoteEventEmitter();
  con.pipe(remote.getStream()).pipe(con);

  remote.on('dbaction', data => {
    // aquí data puede ser un JSON que tenga
    // el registro creado, actualizado, eliminado
  });
}).listen(STREAM_PORT);
```

El cliente se conecta por el mismo puerto para emitir el evento `dbaction`:

```
import net from 'net';

let con = net.connect(STREAM_PORT, HOST);
let client = new RemoteEventEmitter();
con.pipe(cliente.getStream()).pipe(con);

export client;
export con;
```

Cuando hagas alguna operación en Mongo:

```
import client from '../stream/client';

let post = new Post({ ... });
post.save().then(doc -> (
  client.emit('dbaction', doc)
));
```

Y así le enviamos al servidor remoto el nuevo post creado.

Answer (score 0):

Revisa esta librería:
npmjs .com/package/printer

Por otro lado, definitivamente necesitas una tecnología del lado del servidor para imprimir "algo", ya que el navegador por seguridad tiene bloqueada la impresión automática. Por lo que mencionas necesitas websockets y NodeJS o una tecnología similar para poder enviar un evento hacia otra computadora y que esta pueda imprimir algo. Yo lo hice una vez, aunque no tal como lo pides, sino usé solo PHP bajo Windows. Así lo hice:

1. Instalar PHP y Apache en la computadora Cliente (la que imprimirá el ticket).
2. Creé un archivo imprimir.php el cual creaba un txt (ej. data.txt) con la información que debe imprimir.
3. Creé un archivo .bat que enviará a imprimir dicho archivo data.txt. El .bat lo guardo en la misma ubicación del archivo .php
4. Utilizando la función exec de PHP ejecuto dicho archivo .bat ej. exec("imprimir.bat") (Como imprimir usando un archivo bat robvanderwoude .com/printfiles.php)

Para proceder a imprimir lo que tienes que hacer es recibir la alerta del tipo "imprimir", y ejecutar la ruta //localhost/imprimir.php. Debes temer sumo cuidado con el Cross Origin Domain, así que tu archivo imprimir.php debe tener habilitado el CORS, que es en cristiano la capacidad de poder recibir peticiones de otros orígenes.

Con esta simple (en serio es simple) receta, podrás imprimir tus tickets recibiendo las alertas por websockets.

Comment: Saludos Ricky, me parece interesante tu idea de imprimir con PHP, pero me servirá para imprimir tickets de loterías en cualquier impresora ?

Comment: Hola Rod, claro, eso va a depender de la configuración de la impresora predeterminada en el sistema operativo. Esa técnica manda un flujo de datos a una impresora solamente ¿Cual? La que quieras.

Answer (score 0):

sé que es antigua la publicación pero si vas a imprimir en alguna impresora térmica te recomiendo utilizar la librería de MIKE42 https://github.com/mike42/escpos-php , la estoy utilizando para nuestros sistema de punto de venta y en algunos hay más de 5 equipos en red, los pasos son:

1. Instalar apache o algún servidor web el equipo del cliente.
2. En la carpeta publica del equipo cliente, instalar el script de PHP donde además estará instalada la librería de mike42.
3. Al equipo cliente asignar una IP estática, así el servidor sabrá donde apuntar.
4. Abrir los puertos 80 desde firewall en el equipo cliente, para que permita peticiones.
5. En el equipo cliente habilitar el uso de impresora compartida.
6. Configurar el servidor para que detecte cuando dicha IP estática del cliente realice una petición, posterior a ello, darle la instrucción para imprimir, por ej: "IP estática/imprimir.php".
7. BUALA! ya tienes tu impresión.

Espero le sirva a alguien esta información, ya que hay poca documentación certera en la www.