# ¿Cómo se puede trabajar con impresoras en NodeJS?

Tags: nodejs

Estoy desarrollando una pequeña aplicación JavaScript corriendo en NodeJS en la cual se leen datos de una base de datos y, a partir de la información obtenida, se monta un objeto con dichos datos (hasta aquí todo bien). Lo que se requiere es que dichos datos se impriman.

He estado viendo en stackoverflow en inglés algunas soluciones, pero no me quedan claras, aunque he podido deducir que tengo que usar o bien childProcess o bien socket.io, pero no tengo claro cuál usar y cómo conectarlo con la impresora.

Aunque el entorno de pruebas es en Ubuntu, la aplicación se desplegará en un Windows, con el lío que ello conlleva de scripts de impresión y demás. En caso de no poder responder , ¿podrían indicarme, por favor, algún libro, blog o página web que hable sobre ello?.

Fuentes donde he encontrado respuestas:

- [Imprimir con Node después de un evento](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24058/como-puedo-imprimir-autom%C3%A1ticamente-con-node-js-despu%C3%A9s-de-un-evento)
- [Printer + Node + Socket.IO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35935675/how-to-run-both-socket-io-and-socketcluster-in-same-server-but-different-port-us)
- [Usando IPP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19867401/print-job-delay-when-using-ipp-for-node-js) - Esta no me ha quedado muy claro ya que no entiendo como consigue el valor para la variable ipp (que sé que es un protocolo para impresoras en red)
- [Print PDF in Win8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30965249/pdfkit-js-how-to-save-document-to-file-win-8-app)

Comment: Hola Juan, fíjate que StackOverflow en Español no funciona de esa manera. Básicamente las preguntas que piden opiniones o recomendaciones son cerradas rápidamente. Pero te animo a que si tienes algún problema o error implementando la soluciones que hayas elegido, preguntes aquí con toda confianza, siguiendo esta guía [mcve].

Comment: Muchas gracias por la aclaración. Entonces, ¿cómo la cierro?. Mil perdones.

Comment: Creo que hay un botón de borrar, en alguna parte. Tal vez en la barra lateral... la verdad no lo recuerdo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero instalar el paquete

```
npm install node-printer
```

Incluir en el servidor o cliente

```
var Printer = require('node-printer');
var fs = require('fs');
var imagemagick = require('imagemagick-native');
```

Mostrar las Impresoras conectadas y el Status

```
Printer.list();
getPrinters();
```

Convertir tus Datos

```
imagemagick.convert({
srcData: data,
srcFormat: 'PDF',
format: 'EMF',
},  function(err, buffer) {
 if (err) {
    throw 'Error';
 }

// Enviando...

printer.printDirect({
    data: buffer,
    type: 'EMF',
    success: function(id) {
        console.log('Impreso);
    },
    error: function(err) {
        console.error('error');
    }
   })
  })
```

Comment: Había leído sobre este paquete pero preferiría tener minimizadas las dependencias externas. Aún así, si veo que me lío mucho, lo usaré. Muchas gracias por la respuesta.

Comment: Si te ha sido de ayuda, colocarla como util

Comment: Una pregunta. Estoy leyendo al documentación del node-printer e indica que para windows tiene que estar instalado el visual studio, ¿es así?.

Answer (score 0):

Al final creo que voy a lanzar un proceso hijo (ChildProcess) enviado el comando de impresión del propio sistema operativo mediante los comandos `lp` (UNIX) y `net use` (Windows).